# Open Doc file from SD Card within App - Android

Tags: android, dependencies

Android - I dont want to use third party app to open doc, it should be from within app. Any library (dependency) which can help to open ppt, excel and doc.

Comment: Please maintain the professional outlook here, and if anyone doesn't understand the question, Please ask for more clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

[To view Excel sheets](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjxljar.htm) you can use an external lib.

To view .ppt, you must use an external app, here's the code for this:

```
final Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file); 
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"); 

PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
if(list.size() > 0)
   startActivity(context, intent);
```

The same goes for .doc:

```
File targetFile = new File(path);
                    Uri targetUri = Uri.fromFile(targetFile);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "application/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, DOC);
```

Comment: Thankx Sipty for your reply. But i need a dependency that can show within app without calling any intent. Anyway thanks for your effort

Comment: That is not possible, as I mentioned.